# Get option to prewiev or save file after upload

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got a pdf creator on my webapp where my user can create a pdf with different stats. How should I do so they get the option to prewiev or save the file right after the creation of it? the file is saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileNamn + ".pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(dataPdf); //this is byte data*
Response.End();
```

*Make the pdf to byte data and put it in the BinaryWrite